# How to run a single test that is excluded

Tags: gradle, integration-testing

I have integration tests named with "IT" at the end and the tests are excluded by default. My `build.gradle` contains:

```
test {
    if (!project.hasProperty('runITs')) {
        exclude '**/**IT.class'
    }
}
```

The `check` task, which is part of `build`, no longer runs integration tests. All tests (unit + integration) are executed with defined `runITs` (e.g. `./gradlew -PrunITs=1 check`) if it is necessary.

It works very well. The only drawback is than I can't run single integration test with `--test` (used by IDE) without `runITs` defined. The command fails with message: No tests found for given includes: [**/**IT.class](exclude rules).

Is there any way (e.g. build variable) how to recognize the run of single test with `--test` and skip the exclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. My `build.gradle` now contains:

```
test {
    if (!project.hasProperty('runITs') && filter.commandLineIncludePatterns.empty) {
        exclude '**/**IT.class'
    }
}
```

When tests are run with `--tests` then the list `commandLineIncludePatterns` in filter is not empty and exclude is not applied.

Details are obvious in test task source: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/dc8545eb1caf7ea99b48604dcd7b4693e79b6254/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/AbstractTestTask.java

Answer (score 0):

try invoking the test task to the specific sub-project. if the test is root try

`gradle -PrunITs=1 :test --tests 'MServiceTest'`

else

`gradle -PrunITs=1 :sub-prj:test --tests 'MServiceTest'`

Comment: Run with `-PrunITs=1` parameter is of course working. I am looking for a solution when `gradle :test --tests 'MServiceIT'` runs test but `gradle :test` does not.